# python pandas to match a string based on the prefix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a code below where i'm parsing a hostname text file with `pd.read_csv` and getting them matched based on the `prefix` , that works fine. However, as now there is a requirement where in `sj12` i need to look for fourth character as an alphabet, example sj12 should match `sh12[a-z]` ie `sj12a001` , `sj12u003` etc.

I'm looking if there is way in pandas to do this..

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prefixes = ['sj00', 'sj12', 'cr00', 'cr08', 'eu00', 'eu50']

df = pd.read_csv('new_hosts', index_col=False, header=None)
df['prefix'] = df[0].str[:4]
df['grp'] = df.groupby('prefix').cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='grp', columns='prefix', values=0)

#To drop if all values in the row are nan
df = df[ prefixes ].dropna(axis=0, how='all').replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

### Current output with the above code:

```
sj00        sj12        cr00        cr08        eu00        eu50
sj000001    sj124000    cr000011    crn00001    euk000011   eu5000011
sj000002    sj125000    cr000012    crn00002    eu0000012   eu5000013
sj000003    sj12at00    cr000013    crn00003    eu0000013   eu5000014
sj000004    sj12bt00    cr000014    crn00004    eu0000014   eu5000015
```

### Expected Output:

```
    sj00        sj12        cr00        cr08        eu00        eu50
    sj000001    sj12at00    cr000011    crn00001    euk000011   eu5000011
    sj000002    sj12bt00    cr000012    crn00002    eu0000012   eu5000013
    sj000003                cr000013    crn00003    eu0000013   eu5000014
    sj000004                cr000014    crn00004    eu0000014   eu5000015
```

Above in expected output you see `sj124000` and `sj125000` removed.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a data sample and expected output. Also I would suggest to keep only the relevant (pandas part of the code) where you need help..!

Comment: @anky_91, thnx for the revert, i have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved with `str.extract` method.

```
df['sj12'] = df['sj12'].str.extract('(\w\w\d\d\w\*)', expand=True)
```

OR

```
df['sj12'] = df['sj12'].str.extract('(\w{2}\d{2}\w\*)', expand=True)
```